# React State Not Updating on Backspace

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to filter a list of countries with a *live search* feature, but whenever I press the backspace, it does not update the state array.

So I tried searching on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/iamevg/pen/LRLVdY?editors=0010) for potential solutions to my problem and I used the same exact code in this example, but it doesn't work in my case.

Here's the entire component where the search field exists.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import CountryList from '../components/CountryList';
import axios from 'axios'
import SearchForm from '../components/SearchForm';

export default () => {
    const [countries, setCountries] = useState( [] )
    const [search, setSearch] = useState( '' )

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get( 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all' )
        .then( response => {
            setCountries( response.data )
        } )
    }, [])

    const onSearch = e => {
        const searchQuery = e.target.value.toLowerCase()
        setSearch( e.target.value )

        const filteredCountries = countries.filter( country => {
            const searchValue = country.name.toLowerCase()

            return searchValue.indexOf( searchQuery ) > -1
        } )

        setCountries( filteredCountries )
    }

    return (
        <main className="CountriesPage">
            <input
                type="search"
                value={ search }
                onChange={ onSearch }
            />
            <CountryList data={ countries } />
        </main>
    )
}
```

I've also provided a gif [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdIJB.jpg).

Expected results should be a properly updated array of countries when typing and backspacing the live search field.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are filtering your countries array here:

```
const filteredCountries = countries.filter( country => {
     const searchValue = country.name.toLowerCase()

     return searchValue.indexOf( searchQuery ) > -1
} )

setCountries( filteredCountries )
```

At the end you set your countries to the list of filtered countries. If you started with 5 countries you may have now filtered the list in countries down to 0 elements. When you hit backspace you aren't filling that countries array up with the original entries, so when you filter again you are now filtering on a list with nothing in it.

Store your filtered countries in the state and don't set the countries array to the filtered countries. Then display filtered countries instead of countries.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I resolved the solution by reading [Snukus' post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55777907/2924072).

```
export default () => {
    const [countries, setCountries] = useState( [] )
    const [search, setSearch] = useState( '' )
    const [filter, setFilter] = useState( [] ) //added

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get( 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all' )
        .then( response => {
            setCountries( response.data )
        } )
    }, [])

    const onSearch = e => {
        console.log( filter );
        const searchQuery = e.target.value.toLowerCase()
        setSearch( e.target.value )

        const filteredCountries = countries.filter( country => {
            const searchValue = country.name.toLowerCase()

            return searchValue.indexOf( searchQuery ) > -1
        } )

        setFilter( filteredCountries ) // updated
    }

    return (
        <main className="CountriesPage">
            <input
                type="search"
                value={ search }
                onChange={ onSearch }
            />
            <CountryList data={ filter.length ? filter : countries } /> // updated
        </main>
    )
}
```